# Possible to animate nested image with CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a block that displays a series of images when you hover over it using only CSS.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/androbaut/pen/BzqvyL)

**HTML**

```
<div class="logos"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
background: #fff;
}

.logos{
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
margin: auto;
background: url('http://45.79.67.59/logo_thumb_bar.jpg') left center;
}

@keyframes play{
100% { background-position: 2000px; }
}
.logos:hover{
-webkit-animation: notexistent;
animation: notexistent;
animation: play 2.5s steps(5) infinite;
}
```

My question is: would it be possible to animate an "img" nested within the main "div" instead of animating the 'background-image' with 'background-position'? I need the image to 'fill' the div it's inside of when the screen is resized, and achieving this with a 'background-image' has been a head-scratcher.

Any suggestions/advice will be much appreciated!

(I'm definitely not opposed to using Javascript/jQuery if necessary, simply wanted to see if what I'm trying to do is possible with CSS alone)

Comment: did you already came across the CSS transform scale() function ? Quite powerfull for CSS, maybe enough for your case.

Comment: Haven't tried that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you size the div using viewport units, and set the background-size to cover it should work with CSS, and be responsive.

[codepen](http://codepen.io/simplesthing/pen/yJRGzE)

```
body {
  background: #fff;
}

.logos {
  width: 40vw;
  height: 40vw;
  margin: auto;
  background: url('http://45.79.67.59/logo_thumb_bar.jpg');
  background-size: cover;

}

@keyframes play {
    100% { background-position: 200vw; }
}
.logos:hover{
  -webkit-animation: notexistent;
    animation: notexistent;
  animation: play 2.5s steps(5) infinite;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to address my question, this was the solution I needed!

Comment: I'm so glad it helped!